# How can I force a group of classes to require a method with variable paramters

Tags: php

My application has a group of similar classes that all require a method with a specific name, but the number of parameters is variable. Using an abstract or interface requires the extending/implementing class method to use the same number of parameters.

e.g. (this won't work but is essentially what I want to do)

#### Abstract Collection

```
abstract class Collection
{
  abstract public function add ($id, $name);
}
```

#### Box Collection

```
class BoxCollection extends Collection
{
  public function add ($id, $name, $color)
  {
    $this->data[] = compact('id', 'name', 'color');
  }
}
```

#### Shape Collection

```
class ShapeCollection extends Collection
{
  public function add ($id, $name, $edges)
  {
    $this->data[] = compact('id', 'name', 'edges');
  }
}
```

I know I could accept an associative array (potentially checking it and throwing an exception if required keys aren't present) but this doesn't help the dev when they are inputting the data, I want the IDE to be able to hint the required parameters.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Maybe it's an option to make them nullable in some cases? eg `$color = null` on functions that don't need it. Not the best looking solution, but it would get the job done.

Comment: PHP doesn't allow for method overloading. having said that, you can make your base class/interface to have a method which "does not take any parameters". But in reality we know that we can pass any number of parameters to a method in PHP, even more than those that were defined in the method declaration. So your child classes can just use methods like `func_get_args` and `func_​num_​args` whenever they are overriding the base class/interface method.

Comment: You could use the ... operator in the abstract class if you're on php5.6 or higher.

Comment: @Jarek.D - This won't allow hinting when using an IDE though, which is the main thing I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `BoxCollection::add` make the `color` argument optional by adding a default value that makes sense. You won't get any errors then.
If in another class you want to give only the `id` parameter to this method, give a default value to `name` parameter, possibly `null` will do.

Comment: Give a default value to $color and $edges parameters and it will be valid PHP code.

Comment: Also, you can change the names of the parameters in each class if you want. Names do not have to agree.

Comment: Good to know, cheers. I edited your answer with some example code to hopefully make this clearer to others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `...` operator (available since php 5.6)

```
abstract class Collection
{
  abstract public function add ($id, ...$params);
}
```

The concrete classes wouldn't need to be changed then at all

Comment: That's a good option but he will have to declare like this add($id, ...$args). always use the ... operator on the 2nd argument. When calling the functions it will be ok to use different arguments though.